# 500 code error response after a post request in jmeter

Tags: ajax, jmeter, http-post, badboy

well i have record a script using Badboy and export it to Jmeter. the script include a post request that initiates a file with a name.

Parameter send with the request

`noCache=1404378079862
{"alf_destination":"workspace://SpacesStore/${UUID}","prop_cm_name":"File _2","prop_cm_title":"","prop_cm_description":""}`

Every time I run the test plan i get an 500 error code (internal server error) response for the POST request it looks like this

`{
    "status" : 
  {
    "code" : 500,
    "name" : "Internal Error",
    "description" : "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
  },`

so i used chrome developer tool to capture the request and i've found that when i attempted to create a file with name that is already exist the server respond with the 500 error code also i found that the request that is sent by jmeter is different than what i captured with developer tool 
hear isthe one sent by jmeter:

> POST
>   https://${ServerName}/share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm%3acontent/formprocessor

and hear is the one i captured by the developer tool:

> POST https://${ServerName}/share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm%3acontent/formprocessor?noCache=1404586721426&{"alf_destination":"workspace://SpacesStore/${uuid}","prop_cm_name":"file_2,"prop_cm_title":"","prop_cm_description":"","prop_cm_content":"Ramadan kareem","prop_mimetype":"text/plain","prop_app_editInline":"true"}

i changed that name of the file i want to create but still getting the same error 
i have searched for solution but nothing changed. i tried to clear the cache and cookies after each iteration but it also did not work.

and here are the full request made by jmeter

> POST https://${server}/share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm%3acontent/formprocessor
>
> POST data:
>   noCache=1404586721426&%7B%22alf_destination%22%3A%22workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2F${uuid}%22%2C%22prop_cm_name%22%3A%22file_2%2C%22prop_cm_title%22%3A%22%22%2C%22prop_cm_description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22prop_cm_content%22%3A%22Ramadan+kareem%22%2C%22prop_mimetype%22%3A%22text%2Fplain%22%2C%22prop_app_editInline%22%3A%22true%22%7D=
>
> Cookie Data:
>   $Version=0; JSESSIONID=6508CDFBEF16F2D601CF1E672EB00D62.worker2; $Path=/share/; alfLogin=1404810408; $Path=/share; alfUsername3=jmeter01; $Path=/share; NSC_NzTibsf_TTM=ffffffff09f01c8f45525d5f4f58455e445a4a42378b; $Path=/
>
> Request Headers:
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Alfresco-CSRFToken: ${COOKIE_Alfresco-CSRFToken}
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Length: 359
>   Host: myshare.kfshrc.edu.sa
>   User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

can any one explain why i get this error?

Comment: Are you able to access "workspace://SpacesStore/" from your PC ??

Comment: yes i tried it on both chrome and IE9

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the rest of stacktrace? It doesn't expose the main cause and the cause may be different.

I expect that if you're trying to performance test Alfresco system of version 4.1.7 or higher the request may fail due to  CSRF filter protection which is being set via cookie and needs to be sent as `Alfresco-CSRFToken` header.

To bypass it consider the following:

1. Add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. In *jmeter.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) define the following property: `CookieManager.save.cookies=true`
3. Restart JMeter (property change is not dynamic)
4. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of the request which is failing. Populate it as follows:

   - Header 1

     - Name: `Alfresco-CSRFToken`
     - Value: `${__javaScript(decodeURIComponent("${COOKIE_Alfresco-CSRFToken}"),)}`
   - Header 2

     - Name: `Content-Type`
     - Value: `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i will add more details

Answer (score 0):

It's because the file might be corrupted in the server side. Mostly this is due server side problem. Try with different site to reproduce it.

Comment: what do you mean by "Try with different site to reproduce it."?

Comment: I mean just test with some other site to get the result

Comment: what is the relation between the site i am testing and the other sites i mean i did not get the point of doing this